# Read huge csv file in R from Hadoop

Tags: r, csv, hadoop

I am trying to read huge (250 MB, 0.6 million rows, 60 columns) CSV files in R from Hadoop. The field separator I am using is "@" and the R code I am using is

```
PC2009 <- as.matrix(from.dfs("hdfs://..../apps/g00008/moloy/fuzzy/TUSOpsSODetails_2009.csv", 
           make.input.format(format="csv", sep="@", fill=TRUE))$val)
```

But from 5th column onwards the data is getting corrupted. I found data to be correct in HDFS by doing a "cat". Could anyone please educate me how to read such big files in R from Hadoop? Please note that I am new to MapReduce.

Comment: Edited to improve readability but you do need to also put in the `library`-call that provides the `from.dfs` function and whatever package provides an `as.matrix` method that supports the 'make.input.format' argument if it is not also part of that package. And less than a million records with 60 columns is only a moderate-sized data object these days

Comment: Agree with @BondedDust. 250 MB is not really huge. `fread` from package data.table should read that very quick. However, that you apparently need `fill = TRUE` would prevent you from using it.